# What is remote variable and local variable?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

This is not my codes and i'm using it to set up a chatapp room. However i don't really understand like why does it have **localParticipant** and **remoteParticipants**, how different they are and what they are exactly used for? Can anybody explain me! Thank you so much!

```
const Room = ({ roomName, token, handleLogout }) => {
      const [room, setRoom] = useState(null);
      const [participants, setParticipants] = useState([]);
    
      const remoteParticipants = participants.map(participant => (
        <p key={participant.sid}>{participant.identity}</p>
      ));
    
      return (
        <div className="room">
          <h2>Room: {roomName}</h2>
          <button onClick={handleLogout}>Log out</button>
          <div className="local-participant">
            {room ? (
              <p key={room.localParticipant.sid}>{room.localParticipant.identity}</p>
            ) : (
              ''
            )}
          </div>
          <h3>Remote Participants</h3>
          <div className="remote-participants">{remoteParticipants}</div>
        </div>
      );
    });
```

Comment: It seems like, that you are asking as about Your data structure there....

Comment: i mean i don't know where the localParticipant come from, obviously you can't see the varible remoteParticipant being announced anywhere...